# Slick 2D How to check if the user is hitting only ONE key

Tags: keyboard, slick2d

I'm working on a 2D Game, and I have a problem.
I'm working with Slick 2D.
I can check which key is the user hitting.
But I don't know how to check if the user is pressing nothing.
I want the game to know that if I press the up key and the right key, it shall move in the direction. I already programmed all the multiple key stuff input.

How do I tell slick 2D: *If the user has hit only one Key then something should happen.*

The input is defined as :

```
Input input1 = gc.getInput();
```

in my update Method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick and dirty solution is to create a method to check for the particular keys that you want to know are not being pressed down at the moment, for example the arrow keys:

```
private boolean areKeysPressed(Input input) {
if (input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_LEFT) || input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_RIGHT) || input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_UP) || input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_DOWN)) return true;
else return false;
}
```

And then in your update() method you can do the following:

```
if (!areKeysPressed(input1)) {
//code for what you want to happen if none of the arrow keys are pressed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The question you are asking does not make much sense.

If the game container registers that a key has been hit it triggers the listener 
`void keyPressed(int key, char c)` and you must write yourself which keys do actions and what actions are taken.

If the game does not register a key input, then there is no action taken by `void keyPressed(int key, char c)` and you can safely assume no keys are pressed.

My question to you is, why do you need to check if the user does not press anything? The game should just continue its normal state or move in the same direction until another key is pressed or a game violation occurs.